# Is there any way to distinguish touch vs. mouse interactions in Windows 8 (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, touch, windows-8, mouseevent

I'm currently building an app that has lots of emphasis on panning, which looks and feel beautiful when touched and manipulated. However, when using a mouse, with the typical Microsoft 'blocky' touchwheel, the panning obviously has the same 'blocky' panning effects. Is there any way to detect the different input when developing for windows 8, seeing as how the JS events are now bundled under the same 'MSPointer' name, so I can account for the scrolling behavior differently?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem specifically within my JS code... when monitoring the scrolling action, I keep track of the previous scroll position as well as the current scroll position, by monitoring how quickly this grows or falls, I determine if the user is using smooth 'pixel-by-pixel' scrolling devices (touch or a smooth scrolling mousewheel) or if they are using a 'blocky' mousewheel. As far as solving this problem in general, there doesn't seem to be a Microsoft supported solution..

Comment: You can listen for the manipulation events, which are touch only.
Why do you specifically want to differentiate?

Comment: Because scrolling with a finger vs. scrolling with a 'blocky' mousewheel are two different experiences, and in my case should be handled differently...

Comment: I see. I'm curious how you're going to adapt dynamically. I often move from mouse to touch and back again, all in the same user session.

Comment: Yeah, it is a tricky issue. My current handling, which seems like the best solution, causes a touch-driven interaction to be more 'alive' and responsive than the mousewheel interaction, which has a delayed animation added to it to ensure a 'smooth' experience.. however seeing as how Win8 is still more likely to have more desktop users than tablet users (for the time being), I still think its important to have a somewhat distinct experience that takes desktop use into account. Switching back and forth (which was the reason I wanted to add this in the first place) is not too unnerving

Comment: I await seeing how this interaction falls out. Using Win8 on a touch & mouse device for months, I've not found anything jarring between the two worlds.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wrestling with the same problem and have discovered that there is actually a way to distinguish the input type using the non-standard "pointerType" property of the event. Admittedly, romeboards mentions "app", and this seems like a JavaScript/IE10 solution so I'm not sure if it's appropriate to their problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh772359(v=vs.85).aspx

I know this is an old(-ish) question but it came up early when I was looking for a solution, so I thought I'd add the info.